# Set innerHTML to Vue Compent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im using VueJS and JsPanel to Create a Draggable Window using the following code:

```
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserData", 'julienfade');
    console.log(jsPanel)
    jsPanel.create({
      theme: 'primary',
      headerTitle: '',
      position: 'center 50 50',
      callback: function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('Preview').innerHTML)
        this.content.innerHTML = '?'
      }
    });
  }
```

To set the content of the Window i have to set the innerHTML (which currently is '?'). But i need to render a Vue Component in it. But obviously i cant do `this.content.innerHTML = '< Component />'` because it wont be rendered. How do i render a html string out of the Component to set the innerHTML.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. I think you will be better of if you replace jsPanel with a Vue alternative.

Comment: It looks like a Vue wrapper for jsPanel exists, which might be useful for you: https://64robots.github.io/vue-js-panel/